# Сколько точек функции f(x) при заданных x расположены выше данной прямой

Tags: python

Нужна помощь.Задание звучит следующим образом:Значения функции f(x)=3x^2+2x+1 определены при x=x0(hx)xn. Определить, сколько точек функции f(x) при заданных x расположены выше прямой y=x+3

```
from math import *
print("Введите исходные данные")
print("x0 = ", end='')
x0 = float(input())
print("xs = ", end='')
xs = float(input())
print("x2 = ", end='')
x2 = float(input())
print("Вы ввели:")
print("x0 = %.1f  xs = %.1f  x2 = %.1f" % (x0, xs, x2))
x = x0
y = 3*(x**2) +2*x +1
while x <= x2 + xs / 2:
    y = 3*(x**2)+2*x+1
```

Я начал делать код.Что нужно добавить,чтобы показывало,сколько точек функции при заданных х расположены выше прямой y=x+3??

Comment: Да собсно с тебя просят количество решений неравенства `3x^2+2x+1 > x+3` на заданном промежутке с заданным шагом дискретизации. Так что тупо пробегаешь по всем точкам и считаешь те, в которых неравенство истинно.

Comment: @Akina
Понял,спасибо. А как код написать,чтобы он это сам считал??